# How to create a sliding FB Like Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, css

Newbie in programming (Javascript/HTML5/CSS3) I would like a replica of this clean "slide from left" action button on my home page on first visit (ideally or once like should not annoy users) - can some one provide me step by step directions please?

[FB Like button slides from left image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsLsI.png)

You can see it in live action at this url http://lty.in/ihEAuw once you scroll down a few images/pages.

I really like how clean this is and less intrusive than unlock content coding, you agree?

Comment: What code have you tried so far to accomplish this? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, you know...

Comment: @dat3450 Good point, I have only tried a content unlocker, which I dont prefer and a simple add like and share code which can be placed anywhere (not much formatting). However wanted to learn, this more so for its looks. I will continue to work on developing a basic slide left "button/div" while I seek the community support.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this styles :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .main-wrapper{
            width:400px;
            height:400px;
            margin:20% auto;
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:red;
        }
        .btn{
            width:200px;
            height:30px;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:50px;
            display:block;
            border:none;
            background-color:blue;
            color:#fff;
            left:-170px;
            text-align:right;
            transition:all ease-in-out .2s;
        }
        .btn:hover{
            left:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <button class="btn">your btn</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```